# How to use memray with Gunicorn or flask dev server?

Tags: python, flask, memory, gunicorn

I want to profile my flask project memory using [memray](https://github.com/bloomberg/memray).
In the documentation it is said to use the command as:

```
memray run my_script.py
```

But when I run flask (using dev server) or gunicorn I don't define the entry script:

```
flask run -port 80
```

So when I try to run the same thing but with memray:

```
memray run flask run -port 80
```

it throws an error saying `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flask'.`

How to achieve this?

Comment: Did you try to give the full path to `flask`?

Comment: @KlausD. That worked! Can you put it as an answer?